# How do you use table data in an alias for a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias, string-concatenation, sqlfiddle

I'd like to reference data from a record in the name that I give the column that a `SELECT` query returns. I've tried this, but it's not liking the extra `SELECT` that I'm trying to concatenate into the alias:

```
SELECT Table1.Field1 AS "Pick any " & 
  CAST((SELECT Table2.Field1
  FROM Table2
  WHERE Table2.ID = 1) AS VARCHAR(3))
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.Field2 = "Value"
```

What I want to see is:

```
+------------+
| PICK ANY 4 |
+------------+
| Value1     |
| Value2     |
| Value3     |
| Value4     |
| Value5     |
| Value6     |
+------------+
```

Comment: I don't think any DBMS supports this (but maybe it would help if you tagged yours). I think you'll need dynamic SQL for something like that or do it in the application if there is any up front. And by the way SQL typically uses single quotes to enclose string values not double quotes. So `WHERE Table1.Field2 = "Value"` should rather read `WHERE Table1.Field2 = 'Value'`. (But double quotes are fine in many DBMS for identifiers including aliases, so `AS "Pick any "` is fine, don't get that mixed up.)

Comment: It's just in SQL Fiddle - I'm building a sample schema to demonstrate a bigger issue I'm having in MS Access - this bit is just a helpful label to put into the query results so people can see what they're looking at.  Could I somehow just do a select query that returns a specific string and nothing else?

Comment: This is something that is database specific. In SQL Server you can use dynamic SQL. But as soon as you use dynamic SQL you need to question your database design. What you're doing certainly has a design smell. What's the bigger picture here?

Comment: @IsaacReefman . . . A SQL query has fixed columns, in a fixed order, with fixed types.  You cannot have variable values, unless you use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I don't need this for the end product, but it would make it easier asking for help if I can put the number into the column name. I'm using the MS Sql Server version in SQL Fiddle, which would imply that I can use dynamic SQL - if you can explain how I'd make that work in Dynamic SQL that'd be cool - I have no intention of using such a thing within the actual database though - again; just a visual tool for people helping me on the other question.

Comment: My solution is currently to use a separate `SELECT` query to return a one row one column table telling you how many to pick before the second select query happens. This is fine, and it doesn't *need* to be elegant, but now I've asked the question I'm wondering how you *would* do it, seeing as in this example it would neaten up the presentation (as I don't have any forms in SQL Fiddle)